# Text is blur and not correctly displaying

Tags: three.js

i am trying to display text using three js but the text displayed is slight diagonally and blur. 
i am attaching screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a live demo with your code? Use this as a starter template: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6145/      this is fiddle but i don't know why it's not working. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set a resolution of your canvas. I've applied a value of 512x512 and also increased the font size. Your text should be more sharp now.

```
canvas.width = 512; 
canvas.height = 512;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6147/

BTW: Always use `CanvasTexture` in such scenarios. In this way, you don't have to set `needsUpdate` to `true`.

Comment: I want to display different texts at different-different coordinates.so can you please tell what changes are required in my createLabel function.

Comment: I though your function already has the signature for this task. In any event, please don't ask multiple questions in the same thread. Create a new one or use the `three.js` forum (https://discourse.threejs.org/) instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101878/display-texts-at-different-different-coordinates-using-three-js . It is related question so can you please help me in this